# How to add filter action for File Upload Control in Asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, file-upload

I need to get an image url using FileUpload Control. When i do it in the explorer it shows all files to select. But i need to show only ".jpg,.gif" files. How can i do it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as I remember file upload control does not allow you to restrict files for specific extensions. All you can do is validate , have a look at this article [Adding Filter Action to FileUpload Control of ASP.NET 2.0](http://aspalliance.com/1614_Adding_Filter_Action_to_FileUpload_Control_of_ASPNET_20.all)

Answer (score 0):

In standard html, i am not sure if this can be done (especially for all browsers) see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521122/html-input-type-file-apply-a-filter)

I have done this using a flash uploader, eg uploadify

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because the underlying < input type='file' / > html element does not support that. In order to have such filtering you ought to use Flash/Silverlight uploader, like the [Telerik RadAsyncUpload.](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/upload/examples/async/validation/defaultcs.aspx?product=asyncupload)

Comment: Thanks Sergeev. I will use Telerik Control.