# How to restrict file upload to JPG, PNG, and GIF in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using a simple input box `<input type="file" />` in a HTML form, and I want to enforce that only JPG, PNG, and GIF files can be uploaded.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML <input type='file'> apply a filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521122/html-input-type-file-apply-a-filter)

Comment: @Ahsan I agree with Ravi.  But please note, this only checks the name of the file being uploaded.  The actual format or content of the file could still be anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can check this link, [CodeProject: Image uploading](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79043/An-Example-ASP-NET-MVC-Web-Project-to-Upload-and-D)

```
  $file = $("#yourFileuploadID");
                var $filePath = $.trim($file.val());
                if ($filePath == "") {
                    alert("Please browse a file to upload");
                    return;
                }

                var $ext = $filePath.split(".").pop().toLowerCase();
                var $allow = new Array("gif", "png", "jpg", "jpeg");
                if ($.inArray($ext, $allow) == -1) {
                    alert("Only image files are accepted, please browse a image file");
                    return;
                }
```

PS : It's better to have server side validation, it will be handy when javascript is disabled at client side.  make sure you check for both

Comment: Javascript will not be enough.  You also have to check the file on the webserver to verify that the mime type is correct.

Comment: that is there. we need both client and server validation

Comment: @Ravi if the file user selected to upload  contains (".") then what ?

Comment: @Ahsan check for Last Instance of  "."