# Upload specific files only

Tags: html

I would like to limit the user to upload only specific files.I know it can be done through php script which the form action value is leading to but that's not what I'm looking for.

When the user is choosing a file after using that line:

```
<input type="file" ... />
```

He got an option to select all files

[image]

I want to change it only to a specific extensions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [restrict file upload selection to specific types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575482/restrict-file-upload-selection-to-specific-types)

Comment: check this topics :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938124/how-to-filter-input-type-file-dialog-by-specific-file-type
or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521122/html-input-type-file-apply-a-filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `accept` attribute. For example if you wanted to limit to all image files:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

You could also specify a list of possible types:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*,video/*" />
```

Needless to say that legacy browsers that do not support this new attribute will behave exactly as shown in your screenshot and completely ignore this attribute and there's nothing you could do about it.

In all cases you should provide a server side validation of the actual file type being uploaded and never rely on the client to ensure this.

Comment: The `accept` attribute has been around since at least [HTML 3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#input).

Comment: @Quentin, good point, I didn't know that. And how do older user agents behave when they encounter it? Is this supported in older browsers? Sorry for asking but I no longer have such browsers under my hands to test.

Comment: It does change it to "Images only" but I have an option to change it to "All files" again and choose what ever I want.

Comment: @ImriPersiado, that's the best you can get on the client. Sorry you will have to live with that, or write your own web browser which will behave differently. Alternatively you could use some Flash plugin where this can be restricted.