# chromium embedded framework: file type filter in a dialog box

Tags: dialog, filedialog, imagefilter, chromium-embedded, filefilter

I am working with the cef dialogs to filter the viewable file types inside the dialog box

I only want the user to see common image files like jpeg, gif, png. 
So far I have something that works but in the dialog box, the option is titled PNG Images. That is wrong because it should be just Images not PNG Images.

I tried following the sample that came with cef and building off it.
([sample](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/source/browse/branches/1180/cef3/tests/cefclient/dialog_test.cpp?r=864))

My code is

```
  std::vector<CefString> file_types;
  file_types.push_back(".png;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif");
  browser->GetHost()->RunFileDialog(FILE_DIALOG_OPEN, "Open Icon File",
    "", file_types, new RunFileDialogCallback(message_name));
  return true;
```

The following works

```
file_types.push_back(".png;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif");
```

But I do not know how to give this filter a name

Comment: An Image for clarification can be cound here http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=10915&e=0

Comment: You can specify filters on HTML, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521122/html-input-type-file-apply-a-filter?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be usefull for someone in 2022, who use jcef (java cef):

```
Vector<String> file_types = new Vector<String>();
file_types.add(".csv");
manager.getBrowser().runFileDialog(CefDialogHandler.FileDialogMode.FILE_DIALOG_OPEN, "Choose CSV", null, file_types, 0, dialogCallBack);
}
```