# Sonata Media Bundle - Upload only certain Mimetypes

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I will upload only certain extensions/MimeTypes, e.g. jpeg. I searched the half day long and only find bad solutaions.

I don't want to validate after upload. Perfect would be, if I could see only the files with the right extensions. The typical dropbox:

Is there a way to do that with the Media Bundle?

Comment: if [the config option](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/3-x/doc/reference/advanced_configuration.html#advanced-configuration) is not enough, please checkout the the [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521122/html-input-type-file-apply-a-filter) about the _typical dropbox_ options. You will need to find the template for the media upload form and apply the selected solution to.